# WebRequest not working to an existing URL

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core, stream, webrequest

The code below has worked, now it doesn't. The url I want to reqeust exist, but it takes a while to load because it generate a PDF file. It returns 404 not found immediately. It is like await async doesn't work.

```
var request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create($"http://moachingtestweb.azurewebsites.net/FoodPlanner/Pdf?foodplanId={foodplanId}");
//var request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create($"https://application.moaching.com/FoodPlanner/Pdf?foodplanId={foodplanId}"); //TODO for prod. Add to config.
request.Method = "GET";
var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");
```

Comment: Have you taken the exact URL the application is using and put it in your browser?

Comment: @howcheng Yes. And it works. I have also tried to make a request to the base url and that works to. But when i load the URL that you see in the code it return 404 right wait. As said the url take time to reload. This website is hosted in Azure app service.

Comment: Well if it's coming back with a 404 that's the server response; the web request isn't going to just tell you Not Found for no reason. Perhaps you need to set `request.Credentials`? Sorry, I don't use Azure web sites, so I'm not that familiar with how authentication/authorization work there.

Answer (score 0):

If you think its timeout, then increase [timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.timeout?view=netframework-4.8) and try.

```
// Set the 'Timeout' property in Milliseconds.
myWebRequest.Timeout=10000;
```